# List of queryParams is empty in Angular 5 routing

Tags: angular, typescript, router, optional-parameters, angular-activatedroute

I'm new to Angular and I've looked for solution of my problem, but unfortunately I haven't found that.
When I 'm passing parameters to the router (class Router), but list of params (on target site) is empty.

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras ={
  queryParams: {
    uri: item.uri
  }
}

this.router.navigateByUrl('articlelist/article-details', navigationExtras);
```

Article-details component (route is ActivatedRoute class):

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log("ArticleDetailsComponent " + JSON.stringify(this.route.url));
    this.route.queryParamMap.map(paramMap =>{
            this.uri = paramMap.get('uri');
            console.log(this.uri);
        });
    }
```

Routing in ArticleList module (one of modules in my project):

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: ArticleListComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'ArticleList'
    },
  },
{
  path: 'article-details',
  component: ArticleDetailsComponent,
  data: {
    title: 'ArticleDetails'
  },
}
];
```

When I logged route.url in target component the result was:

> ArticleDetailsComponent
>   {"_isScalar":false,"observers":[],"closed":false,"isStopped":false,"hasError":false,"thrownError":null,"_value":[{"path":"article-details","parameters":{}}]}

If somebody knows how to fixed it, I'll be grateful for help :)

Comment: Try ```console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap)``` inside of your ngOnInit

Comment: {"params":{}} this is a result

Comment: Did you try with a hard coded string instead of item.uri, it might be undefined.
Can you see the query string params on browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should need to use `ActivatedRoute` in order to get all query params.

Try this -

```
constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      const URI = params['uri'];
    });
```

## Update

Try to send params like this -

```
this.router.navigate(['articlelist/article-details' ], {
      queryParams: {
        uri: item.uri || 'Default'
      }
    });
```

Comment: params['uri'] is undefined :/

Comment: are you sure params is sending properly while routing

Comment: How to check this ?

Comment: check in the browser URL

Comment: No, your query params is not sending properly, check my updated answer and do your code like that

Comment: I understand `ActivatedRoute` is `BehaviourSubject` behind the scene so by default it sends null or no query params even if  params exisit in the URL. I want to use lettable operators using `pipe` and `mergeMap`  and then use this param to make HTTP service call; however in mergemap param is always empty ! Any solution for this problem?

Comment: i always get 2 events, the first is empty the second is ok, how to avoid the empty one? Becaus if it is empty i must trigger an http request, and i cannot know if ther will come a second or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the param  in your app.routing.module.ts:

```
{ path: 'examplePath/:id', component: YourComponent},
```

and send like that:

```
this.router.navigate(['/examplePath/' + id]); (with @angular/router/Router)
```

Then in your component constructor you can get param (with @angular/router/ActivatedRoute):

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.yourObject = params['id'];
}
```

Comment: thats not a query param

Comment: it is. You can also subscribe to activatedroute.queryParams in the same manner

Answer (score -2):

Instead of relying on Observables, I would advise you to get a snapshot of your route. This will give you a simple object containing your params.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, result is an empty list :/

Comment: Then you have an issue with your routing. Please post a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: I also see an empty list.  When I use the `this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe` form, I do get the query parameters eventually, but if I use the `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams` form that's empty.  It's like the snapshot is being taken too early.